# How to determine what commands a FreeBSD rc script runs

Tags: freebsd, rc

I'm having problems starting a service managed by `rc`. I can't see anything in `/var/log` that looks relevant, so I'd like to try running the command manually.

I know I can read through the script in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d`, but it does enough magic that I'd probably miss something. Is there a flag or command that will show what an `rc` script would do without actually doing it?

Comment: What command is it?  What script is failing?  RC scripts are, in reality, *typically* just wrappers ...

Comment: I ended up manually reading through the script. I asked for a general solution so I'd know what to do in the future for other services.